# Monero nodejs mining documentation

Tags: monerod

I have a simple question. Is there any documentation on how mining software works on Monero with nodejs? Or how should I connect with the blockchain and get some data to process it?

I've looked already on Google but I can't find anything solid.

Thanks in advance

JPP

Answer (score 1):

> ...how mining software works on Monero with nodejs?

Mining "works" the same irrespective of the platform the pool/miner is built on.

Documentation of a nodejs based pool can be found at [nodejs-pool](https://github.com/Snipa22/nodejs-pool).

Comment: So if I understand it correct I need to connect to the pool somehow in nodejs en then I get some work from the pool? But then my program needs to process the work right?

Comment: Get work from a pool or daemon, hash it repeatedly with the RandomX hashing algo until you get a hash which meets the required target, then submit.

Comment: By required target you mean the hash is a valid hash which can be added to the blockchain? Thanks for all your help. This project will be open source so all developers can learn from it.

Comment: A hash is just a number. It must be smaller than another number, which is the inverse of a number miners call a target. Specifically, if hash * diff < 2^256-1 it meets the required network difficulty, or put in target terms, if 2^256-1 / hash >= diff_target it meets the requested difficulty target.

Comment: Also, hashes are not added to the blockchain, blocks are, which include a nonce, that when others hash the block data with the nonce, the resulting hash must meet the network difficulty.

Comment: Okay so in brief, connect to a pool, get work from a pool. Change the nonce, rehash the blockheader until its <= diff_target. If yes submit share to pool. Blockchain broadcast to the other miners. One last question. XMR latest algorithm is infeasible for browser mining. I was planned to use ETN(or any other CPU coin). But how can I get work from a pool? Is it as simple as an http req?

Comment: If you want answers for other coins I suggest asking in those communities.

Comment: Its more about the thought behind the mining system. Let's say I stick with XMR instead of ETN. Are my thoughts right in brief? I guess am wrong with the http req :-)

Comment: Mining RandomX from a web browser in infeasible due to memory requirement (2+GB).

Comment: Yess I know(that's why I said I go for ETN) but for all miners is the connection to the pool/deamon the same right? But I don't know how that's done. I suppose it ain't is a simple http req? The coin doesn't matter because it goes about the pow system which is basicly the same.

Comment: I've tried const Daemon = require('monero-rpc').Daemon
 
const daemon = new Daemon('http://pool.minexmr.com:4444');

daemon.getLastBlockHeader((err, header) => {
    if (err){
        console.log(err)
        return;
    } 
    console.log(header)

}) but that gives me a error Socket Hang up. But if I replace the mining pool string what a node http://node.moneroworld.com:18089 then its works fine. What am I missing?

Comment: A pool is not a monero daemon, it's a pool, for mining, which you connect to and use the stratum protocol.

Comment: I got it, do you have a recommendation for a js/npm package? I've tried stratum-client and stratum but stratum-client only works with slush pool for some reason.